# declaring variable in jscript

Tags: c#, javascript

```
string testid = "#imgThumbnail" + (counter + 1);
string stringURL = list[counter]; // return string
//this is the problem
string jsscript = "$('"+testid+"').attr('src','"+stringURL+"'); $('"+testid+"').show();";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "sc", jsscript, true)
```

hi, i having problem to make the jsscript work.
Everything should be fine  (Tested the clientscript with an alert, it works!)
but somehow the jsscript which contain variables and actions cannot work. i don't understand why, and could only assume i write the code wrongly (syntax)

the js is used to assign url into image source (i using asp:Image) and then show the image.
also i calling this from C# backend.

EDIT : there is no error message. When i run the cod, it just go through (break point at the page.clientscript.RegisterStartupScript there, but it just goes through and didn't show any error message). And then no image is display in the end. 
My vs doesnt allow me to break point at frontend aspx page.

Comment: this quiestion does not show any effort

Comment: Please clarify "cannot work" for the people trying to help you. Since this is client-side code you should probably include any errors that are printed in the javascript console of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of these various variables? I don't see you adding quotes around `stringURL` so you are probably winding up with something like this:

```
$('#imgThumbnail3').attr('src',http://www.something.com); $('#imgThumbnail3').show();
```

where the `http://www.something.com` part is obviously bad JavaScript because there are no quotes around it.

Comment: hi, i tried but it didn't work. hmm, i assumed my parameter passing was wrong then tried with alert(++) but it works, so i assume the problem lies at the $('#id of asp:image').attr('src','url')...

Comment: @OoiChiewWei try using asp:image.ClientID. This gives the ID of the element as rendered. This is often different if adding multiple instances of the control (e.g. in a Repeater)

Comment: do you mean like this?
string jsscript = "$get('" + testid + "').src='" + stringURL + "'; $('" + testid + "').show();";
hmm still not showing

Comment: @OoiChiewWei No, I mean like this: `"$('"+testid+"').attr('src','"+stringURL+"'); $('"+testid+"').show();";`. Are you actually looking at the JavaScript that your code is producing?

Comment: @JL, hi sorry for not being clear enough. You did point out the mistake of missing '' and i tried just as you said but still not working. And for latter question: yes, i put a break point and checking the output of the string =).

Comment: @OoiChiewWei Ok, I see. Have you checked the generated HTML to make sure that the element has the ID that you think it does (as jason says, ASP.NET could be changing the ID). If that is the case, you may want to consider accessing it using its class name (and giving it a class if needed) rather than its ID.

Comment: @JL, hi i wonder do you (and Jason) mean make sure the ID is correct(didn't get altered by class or anything)? I hard coded the ID (using if...else to take over the JS job) and it work. So i assume the ID should not a problem. Although if...else can do the job, it is a very long code, i wish to use js (still learning).